# Creating a hyperlink in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create a hyperlink between two bookmarks in VBA word.  Here is the code I have come up with, I get a type mismatch error and am unsure why

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add 
Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TableOfContents_KeyBenefits"), _
Address:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks, SubAddress:="KeyBenefitsTarget"
```

Comment: Does ActiveDocument.Bookmarks need to be a string? i.e. Address:= someStringAddress ?

Comment: From my basic understanding it is a variant data type and doesn't need to be a string? but i could be wrong there

Comment: No. That sounds familiar. Have you tried passing a string?

Comment: Try `Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TableOfContents_KeyBenefits").Range` for the first argument.  Address should maybe be `ActiveDocument.FullName`

Comment: Just tried that, instead of a type mismatch error I just got a command failed error, but seems to be on the right track, I will keep messing with that, Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: Thanks to both of you! combining Tim's first part with the string worked, appreciate all the help

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there a reason you're not using Word's built-in Table of Contents generator?

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
     Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TableOfContents_KeyBenefits").Range, _
     Address:=ActiveDocument.FullName, SubAddress:="KeyBenefitsTarget"
```